# is there an error in my use of cv::dct?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use the `cv::dct` function. I create a new matrix, apply the dct to it and display the result:

```
cv::Mat_<float> mTest = cv::Mat_<float>(mTest);
cv::Mat_<float> mTestCV(8, 8);


cv::dct(mTest, mTestCV);

std::cout << "-----CV-----" << std::endl;
for (int u = 0; u < mTest.rows; u++) {
    for (int v = 0; v < mTest.cols; v++) {
        std::cout << (mTestCV.at<float>(u, v));
        std::cout << ",";
    }
    std::cout << "" << std::endl;
}
```

And here's the result (int the second matrix):
[image]

Is there an error somewhere? Where does that 1640 come from?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your [development environment's debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger)?

Comment: Seems you need to [debug your small program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). SO is not how you would go about it. Do you have a concrete question?

Comment: I hear you. My priority is to at least know if I used the build-in function `cv::dct` correctly. So I'll know what results I should get, and then I'll debug. So, that's my question I guess : did I make an error somewhere in the use of `cv::dct`? Because that `1640` in the first cell seems weird.

Comment: @OlivierGrech, that's a better question. But I daresay it merits a shorter code sample to demonstrate. And the wall of text about *why* you ask could then be removed. That way the question would be much clearer, and fit the SO format better.

Comment: I edited my question.